# Creating multiple extract from single mapping in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have below source table.

```
Col1    Col2    Col 3   Col4    col5    col6    col7    col8
A   2   1   2   3   4   5   AAA
B   3   1   1   8   5   6   AAA
C   4   1   2   9   6   7   CC
D   5   2   3   10  7   8   CC
E   2   2   4   11  8   9   CC
F   3   3   5   12  9   10  BB
G   4   3   6   13  10  11  BB
H   5   3   7   14  11  12  BB
I   6   3   8   15  12  13  BB
```

I want to create a single mapping ( 1 source and 1 target stucture) which should create three extract from above source as below. All differnt extract will have different number of columns based on saome speific id.

```
Extract 1
Col1    Col2    Col 3   Col4    col8
A   2   1   2   AAA
B   3   1   1   AAA

Extract 2
Col1    Col2    Col 3   Col4    col5    col6    col7    col8
C   4   1   2   9   6   7   CC
D   5   2   3   10  7   8   CC
E   2   2   4   11  8   9   CC

Extract 3
Col1    Col2    col7    col8
F   3   10  BB
G   4   11  BB
H   5   12  BB
I   6   13  BB
```

I dont want to create three differnt target structure.

Please let us know if any one have any idea on that .

Comment: I don't think it is anyway possible with one target!

Comment: I am doing POC with SQL tranformation with the help of metadata table. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the flow to three pipelines with three `Target Definitions` that all will point to the same `Target Table` on session level. This will be clear and effectively all will end up in same target structure.

Otherwise, if for some reason you's like to avoid having three target instances, you can use the `Union Transformation` that will span the three pipelines and send all data to one target instance.